# SQL Code to forward-fill row values till next non-null rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In the below table, the `[MonthEndDate]` has non-null values. Relative to this, from column `[employeeId]` till column `[jobDescription]` all null values should be **forward-filled with data in the row 4 till row 16** and for last 2 columns i.e. `[StaffTypeID]` and  `[Description]`, all null values should be **forward-filled with data in the row 1 till row 12** and similarly for the remaining rows.

Please use this [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I7ob8A4P) link containing the required CREATE and INSERT statements to generate the table in problem statement.

`Table 1` is table in Problem Statement and `Table 2` is the desired output.

I would be appreciate if you could share the required SQL code.

**`Table 1`**

| MonthEndDate | employeeId | last_day_jobeffectiveDate | employeeType | employeeStatus | scheduledWorkHours | supervisorId | jobCode | jobDescription | StaffTypeID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/31/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 06/30/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 07/31/2013 | E101 | 06/30/2013 | INT | A | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting |  |  |
| 08/31/2013 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting |  |  |
| 09/30/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10/31/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11/30/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12/31/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 02/28/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 03/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 04/30/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 05/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5 | Consultant |
| 06/30/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 07/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 08/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 09/30/2014 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant |  |  |
| 10/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11/30/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12/31/2014 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01/31/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 02/28/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 03/31/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 04/30/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 05/31/2015 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Table 2:

| MonthEndDate | employeeId | last_day_jobeffectiveDate | employeeType | employeeStatus | scheduledWorkHours | supervisorId | jobCode | jobDescription | StaffTypeID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/31/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 06/30/2013 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 07/31/2013 | E101 | 06/30/2013 | INT | A | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 08/31/2013 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 09/30/2013 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 10/31/2013 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 11/30/2013 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 12/31/2013 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 01/31/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 02/28/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 03/31/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 04/30/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 05/31/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 5 | Consultant |
| 06/30/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 5 | Consultant |
| 07/31/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 5 | Consultant |
| 08/31/2014 | E101 | 08/31/2013 | INT | T | 80.0 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | 5 | Consultant |
| 09/30/2014 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 10/31/2014 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 11/30/2014 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 12/31/2014 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 01/31/2015 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 02/28/2015 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 03/31/2015 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 04/30/2015 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |
| 05/31/2015 | E101 | 09/30/2014 | REG | A | 80.0 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | 5 | Consultant |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this just a little differently as I did not use a merge and was also forced to use an additional CTE to fix the employeeStatus issue. I also put my data into a temp table, so you will have to change that in your fiddle. Something like this might work:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT MonthEndDate, MAX(last_day_jobeffectiveDate) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) last_day_jobeffectiveDate ,
          MAX(employeeType) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) employeeType,
         MAX(EmployeeID) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) EmployeeID,
          MAX(scheduledWorkHours) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) scheduledWorkHours ,
          MAX(supervisorId) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) supervisorId ,
          MAX(JobCode) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) JobCode,
          MAX(JobDescription) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) JobDescription,
          MAX(StaffTypeID) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) StaffTypeID,
          MAX(Description) OVER(ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) Description
         , t1.employeeStatus        
FROM #empworkhours t1
),CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT MonthEndDate,
            EmployeeID,
            last_day_jobeffectiveDate,
            employeeType, 
            MAX(employeeStatus) OVER( Partition by last_day_jobeffectiveDate ORDER BY MonthEndDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW ) employeeStatus,
            scheduledWorkHours,
            supervisorId,
            JobCode,
            JobDescription,
            StaffTypeID,
            Description
    FROM CTE
)

UPdATE #empworkhours
    SET employeeId = t2.EmployeeID
    , last_day_jobeffectiveDate = t2.last_day_jobeffectiveDate
    ,employeeType = t2.employeeType
    ,employeeStatus = t2.employeeStatus
    ,scheduledWorkHours = t2.scheduledWorkHours
    ,supervisorId = t2.supervisorId
    ,jobCode = t2.JobCode
    ,jobDescription = t2.JobDescription
    ,StaffTypeID = t2.StaffTypeID
    ,Description = t2.Description
FROM CTE2 t2
INNER JOIN #empworkhours t1 on t1.MonthEndDate = t2.MonthEndDate
```

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you! Here's the updated fiddle for users looking for the complete executable solutions.
https://dbfiddle.uk/I1u0xzSy

Answer (score 2):

This shows only for the columns `employeeId,last_day_jobeffectiveDate` how you can do it.

It uses for every column the **island and gaps algorithm**

You of course have to complete it for the rest

You need to check the `CASE WHEN`for every column, as determins which cases should get then `MAX` values and which not

```
MERGE empworkhours AS tgt  
USING (SELECT
[MonthEndDate],
CASE WHEN
  ([employeeId] IS NULL 
  OR TRIM([employeeId]) = '')
    AND MAX([employeeId]) OVER(
                      ORDER BY MonthEndDate
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) IS NOT NULL
  
  THEN 
  MAX([employeeId]) OVER(
                      ORDER BY MonthEndDate
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ELSE [employeeId] END as [employeeId]
  ,CASE WHEN
  ([last_day_jobeffectiveDate] IS NULL 
  )
    AND MAX([last_day_jobeffectiveDate]) OVER(
                      ORDER BY MonthEndDate
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) IS NOT NULL
  
  THEN 
  MAX([last_day_jobeffectiveDate]) OVER(
                      ORDER BY MonthEndDate
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  ELSE [last_day_jobeffectiveDate] END as [last_day_jobeffectiveDate]
FROM [empworkhours]) as src ([MonthEndDate],employeeId,last_day_jobeffectiveDate)  
ON (tgt.[MonthEndDate] = src.[MonthEndDate])  
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.last_day_jobeffectiveDate IS NULL  
    THEN UPDATE SET tgt.[employeeId] =  src.[employeeId],
                    tgt.[last_day_jobeffectiveDate] = src.[last_day_jobeffectiveDate];
```

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
22 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM empworkhours
```

| MonthEndDate | employeeId | last_day_jobeffectiveDate | employeeType | employeeStatus | scheduledWorkHours | supervisorId | jobCode | jobDescription | StaffTypeID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-05-31 |  | *null* |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | 1 | Accounting Assistant |
| 2013-06-30 |  | *null* |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2013-07-31 | E101 | 2013-06-30 | INT | A | 80 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | *null* |  |
| 2013-08-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 | INT | T | 80 |  | C101 | Intern - Consulting | *null* |  |
| 2013-09-30 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2013-10-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2013-11-30 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2013-12-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-01-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-02-28 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-03-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-04-30 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-05-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | 5 | Consultant |
| 2014-06-30 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-07-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-08-31 | E101 | 2013-08-31 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-09-30 | E101 | 2014-09-30 | REG | A | 80 | S101 | C201 | Staff Consultant | *null* |  |
| 2014-10-31 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-11-30 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2014-12-31 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2015-01-31 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2015-02-28 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2015-03-31 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2015-04-30 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |
| 2015-05-31 | E101 | 2014-09-30 |  |  | *null* |  |  |  | *null* |  |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ROTy9vMM)

Comment: Appreciate your help in providing the solution. 
I added the remaining columns to the script in my fiddle at https://dbfiddle.uk/Yc7Rc_c6
The output is almost as expected.
Except the column [EmployeeStatus], based on row#17, it is forward-filling cell value "T" instead of "A"   for the rows# 18 to 25. 
Could you please suggest the required change.